# create a simple(or dynamic) chart with using AIOTrade library in java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, charts, grid

I have a sceleton code for creating chart. I draw the frame. You only fulfill this source code for creating a chart. It confuses me to create a chart in AIOTrade library. Can you help? Thanks

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ef021bf009b6cc20ab31

I couldn't find enough knowledge about AIOTrade and I don't understand how should I use it. Please help. Thaks again.

Comment: *"Can you help?"* Can you ask a specific technical question? SO is not the place to find a tutor, and as-is, this question is 'too broad'. *"https://gist.github.com/.."* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). And post it here, not at an external site.

Comment: I read that http://aiotrade.com/ but I couldn't understand There is a class in it which names GridChart.java --- How should I use GridChart.java to create A chart with grid.